# To the other side

Tags: star-wars, physics, time, the-empire-strikes-back

> If the Millennium Falcon went into light-speed, it'll be on the other side of the galaxy by now. ~ Admiral Piett

As far as I know, it takes a couple of days to cross the galaxy at light-speed. It's unlikely so much time has passed.

Is this a classic screw-up by a scriptwriter having no clue how space travel works, should this be considered a major exaggeration or has more time passed than I realized?

Comment: I think it is a combination of him using exaggeration as a rhetorical device and pointing out that since they don't know exactly where they went, by the time they find them (Vader then says "Alert all commands. Calculate every possible destination along their last known trajectory.") they could be long gone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, when Admiral Piett says "went into light-speed", he likely means "went to a speed *faster* than light".  It is well known that the hyperdrives appearing in Star Wars are *faster-than-light drives*.

From the [Star Wars Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperdrive):

> In numbers, the hyperdrive allowed travelers to traverse a galaxy spanning over 120,000 light years in only a few hours or days, the exact travel time depending on a number of factors including destination, point of origin, route, and class of hyperdrive.

Even at faster-than-light speeds, the Millennium Falcon would not be on the "other side" of the galaxy so quickly, as you point out, but I suspect that Piett is simply **frustrated** and using **hyperbole** to express that frustration.

Comment: I'm aware light-speed is faster than light. But it isn't *that* fast. Your answer confirms my suspicion.

Comment: @Mast : I just wanted to be clear and complete. :-)

Comment: Speed of travel seems to fluctuate wildly in Star Wars. Several of the books/movies/tv episodes seem to make it seem like it takes several weeks (or even months) for even fast ships to get from the center of the galaxy (i.e. Coruscant) to the outer rim territories. Other times it takes but hours or days. But hey, if anything in Star Wars is consistent, it's the inconsistency.

Comment: Hyperspace travel is *very fast* in the films. Some of the now-decanonized EU books presented a much slower travel time similar to average Star Trek speeds, but none of the films indicated that a trip from Coruscant to the outer rim would take weeks or months. In Episode IV it takes less than a day to get from Tatooine to Alderaan, while the trip from the Death  Star to Yavin also takes less than a day; in AOTC the Jedi get from Coruscant to Geonosis very quickly; and in ROTS Palpatine gets from Coruscant to Mustafar extremely quickly, in what seems to be a matter of hours at most.

Comment: @Praxis I usually give it a while to make sure everyone has voiced his opinion and wait for possible answers. I doubt a better answer will come around, so have a check-mark :)

Comment: @Mast : Thanks.  I wasn't sure if you were a new user or not --- but I see now from your profile that you've been around for a while.  (I usually prompt new users about acceptance to help them learn how the site works.) In any case, your policy about waiting for further opinions is a good one. :-)

Comment: @Mast : By the way, I'm also glad to see that the score for your question is *positive* now.  (It is a genuinely good question.)

Comment: @Praxis Thank you, I was slightly worried because I had no clue what I did wrong. I'm not new to SE, but every site has it's own rules you got to get right.